# Onload issue for Progress bar for preloaded images

Tags: javascript, html, image, onload, preloader

I would like to try and set up a progress bar for several images while their loading and haven't been able to get it to work. I have several images that are preloaded like:

```
var Image1 = new Image();
var Image2 = new Image();
var Image3 = new Image();

Image1.onload = moveProgressBar();
Image2.onload = moveProgressBar();
Image3.onload = moveProgressBar();

Image1.src = url;
Image2.src = url;
Image3.src = url;
```

Something weird is happening since they're immediately running the moveProgressBar() function even though the images aren't entirely loaded yet. This happens even when approaching the page with no cache and with cache. Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The js onload event on images is a big messy mess. Different browsers handle it differently, and different versions (mostly IE) handle it differently. Plus, most browsers have iffy bugs.

Here is a short checklist:

1. set your onload BEFORE you set your src. (Wait for it, it will get quirkier...)
2. Handle onerror as well.
3. Handle images that already was cached. Sometimes they will not fire onload, while other times they will fire and do so imediately.
4. Use a generic belt-and-suspenders setTimeout()-function that polls to see if the image has gotten a width or height in the DOM. This is done differently in different browsers/versions, which means you'll have to use feature detection, starting with naturalWidth, then move on to getAttribute(width) before image.width.

And then you will still probably have some bugs... but you will only know if you test all browser/versions you intend to support.

Comment: 1) No problem. 2) What do I do in case of onerror? 3) How do I handle them to make sure they call onload properly? 4) If I can get their height and width, it means I have the image right? What do I do if it can't find them?

Comment: 2) It depends on your application, but if it is a progress bar, I think you want to tick the progress up one notch, as your progress will otherwise stall at "99%" because of one missing image. 4) Yes, if you can get the width or height and it is greater than 0, the image is loaded. If it is 0 it is not yet loaded. If you can't get the width, you have an odd browser.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, the error was that Noah was calling each function and assigning the result to the onload. It should have been:

```
Image1.onload = moveProgressBar; // note the lack of ()
```